# Auto-open HTML file from Chrome to another browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, windows-7

On downloading a file in Chrome, there does not seem to be a way to auto-open HTML files to a browser other than Chrome.

Opening the HTML file from the Downloads folder opens the file in the default browser, as intended. **However, when Chrome auto-opens the downloaded file, it just opens in Chrome.**

Why I'm asking: I built a Chrome extension that generates an HTML file based on user-selected text in a given webpage. The resulting HTML file, when opened, redirects to another website, to a page that is based on the user's selection. That page does not work properly in Chrome, and it won't for the next 6 months. In the meantime, I learned to program a Chrome extension and I have been blocked on this auto-open problem for 2 weeks.

On Windows 7 without admin privileges.

Comment: There's no built-in API to open files in arbitrary programs. You'll have to write your own simple mediator utility that runs in Windows natively and communicates with your extension via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Why doesn't it work in Chrome?

Comment: 1. Readability: My company's website does not render the same way in Chrome as in IE.

2. Functionality: Certain popups do not open in Chrome, but they do in IE